# Custom WebControl and Postback

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I'm trying to create a few custom web controls wrapping some existing controls. One of them, for instance, is a wrap for a textbox (because I need additional behaviors such as corresponding validators). The problem is, I'm not sure how to get the data of that control to be sent in the postback.

A very simplified example:

```
public class MyTestBox: WebControl
{
protected TB { get; set; }
public Text
{
    get { return TB.Text; }
    set { TB.Text = value; }
}
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
TB= new TextBox()
Controls.Add(TB);
}
}
```

But if I now test a webform with the control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<bleh:MyTextBox ID="MyTextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Then after entering text into the textboxes and submitting, the text in TextBox1 is available in Page_Load, while MyTextBox1.Text is empty. What should I change to have its content available when sending a postback?

*Edit:*

Something I thought of now is to simply check the request form when initializing the control:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    TB.ID = this.ID + "_TextBox1";
    Controls.Add(TB);
    if (Page.Request.Form[TB.UniqueID] != null)
    {
         Text = Page.Request.Form[TB.UniqueID];
    }
}
```

It seems to be working, but feels sort of hacky. Does this seem like a reasonable way?

Comment: is it an option to inherit from System.Web.UI.Textbox ? if so you wouldnt care about Text property you will focus whatever functionality you want to add.

Comment: It is an option in this case, and I might do it.
On the other hand, there are also a bit more complicated controls with a similar issue, where it is more problematic and it might be better to stick with the way I added in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the dynamically generated TextBox an ID, then on the Text property of your control, you should find the TextBox and return its Text.

```
public class BksTextBox: WebControl
{
protected TB { get; set; }
public Text
{
    get 
    { 
       return ((TextBox)this.FindControl("txt")).Text;
    }
}
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
TB= new TextBox()
TB.ID = "txt";
Controls.Add(TB);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting your question.
If you need to add some extra behaviour to a web control you should do the same thing you would do in the case you want extend a class behaviour that is inheritance.
you can Inherits straigh form the TextBox class and add all the extra behaviour you need

```
 public class BksTextBox: TextBox
  {
    //it is just as example
    public string TextToUpperCase
    {
    get
      {
       return Text.ToUpperCase();
       }
     }

}
```

Comment: But how can this be connected to the actual textbox, in a way that when the user changes the text and submits, ViewState["Text"] is updated?

Comment: This still doesn't do the trick, because in the process of the user entering a text and then submitting, the set of the Text property is not accessed and therefore the ViewStart entry is null.

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the Page life cycle. Try to use `this.EnsureChildControls()` in the Text property getter. More on the Page life cycle can be found in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).